# Background audio stops playing when minimize windows 10 universal

Tags: c#, audio, background, uwp, universal

I created an radio app for windows 10 using mediaElement for audio output with AudioCategory = BackgroundCapableMedia but whenever I minimize the app on desktop or mobile the audio stops playing. So how do I keep the audio alive after I minimize? And all examples I find is for 8.1 silverlight applications

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement a Background Task to keep audio alive when your application is minimized.

You can find a sample which targets Windows 10 on github. The project is splitted in 3 parts (a/ your main application b/ the background task and c/ code shared between the two first projects)

[Background audio sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundAudio)

In addition, you can find documentation associated to this sample on MSDN.

[Background Audio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt282140.aspx)

Please let me know if you need additional information.