# Audio Recording in Background is not working C# UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, media

I've checked [Background Audio Stop Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34230341/background-audio-stops-playing-when-minimize-windows-10-universal) , added 
`<uap3:Capability Name="backgroundMediaPlayback"/>` 
in Package.appxmanifest file. For playing m4a file used MediaPlayer class, it works perfectly in background. but for recording audio it is not working in background. It is being muted. Used AudioGraph to recording.

Do i need to handle externally for recording?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. see the comments (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36052992/media-capture-background-task-uwp-windows-10)[here]

Answer (score 1):

Didn't find any solution for this. It seems it is system limitation right now.

We cannot record audio in background on UWP platform.

Answer (score 0):

Remember: when we can’t do something directly by using UWP, we can always create an hybrid UWP/Win32 app, using the UWP bridge.

Best regards